# VBA to click on an image with link on Internet Explorer

Tags: html, vba, excel, internet-explorer

I'm trying to automate the process of entering, logging and extracting some data into a website using VBA on Excel. So far I've managed to log in and navigate to a page where I need to click a button "search", however it's just an image with a link on it:

```
<a tabindex="-1" class="ui-menuitem-link ui-corner-all" href="#" 
onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({s:'formE:j_idt56',u:'formE:vlrDetalhe 
formE:vlrPedidosTot formE:filiais formE:planejamento',f:'formE'});return 
false;" style="width: 80px; left: 240px;">

<img src="/Sip/resources/img/nissan/bt-searc1.png">

<span style="display:none;">Pesquisar</span>

</a>
```

I've searched the web a lot for a solution, but nothing worked so far. This "a tabindex=-1" is part of a div with 4 other "a tabindex=-1" with identical "class" and "href" values, only the "onclick" event is changed, but I can't seem to find a way to look for the event that I mentioned here and trigger it. There's no exclusive value for me to search for. Maybe I could look for the image inside the tag? I'm just starting to learn and I´ve found this code:

```
objIE.document.images(n).Title("bt-searc1.png").Click
```

It gives me an error: "Object does not support this action"

I appreciate any help!

Comment: I need excel to list the username, passwords and dealer codes so I can populate some textboxes, I also need it because the purpose of all this is to export lots of data inside a spreadsheet in excel. Besides, here where I work, I'm not allowed to install programming tools, my boss wants excel to do it. I know it can be done in excel, if you know a way, please just say it.

Comment: I'd love to help, but if I had to do this, I would make an external script to extract relevant data into a csv file, and import that file into excel. Alas if your boss is adamant that everything should fit into excel I guess that's not a solution.

Comment: Try `objIE.document.parentWindow.execScript "PrimeFaces.ab({s:'formE:j_idt56',u:'formE:vlrDetalhe 
formE:vlrPedidosTot formE:filiais formE:planejamento',f:'formE'});return 
false;"`

Comment: Using this I get this error: Could not complete operation. Error 8020101.

Comment: I gave it a quick look, seems to be something related to javascript (?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here's what I came up with:

```
Dim elements As Object, element As Object, count As Long

count = 0
Set elements = objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")

For Each element In elements
    If element.className = "ui-menuitem-link ui-corner-all" Then
        count = count + 1
        If count = 4 Then
        element.Click
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Just added an If inside *Kostas K.'s* If (and thanks a lot!), now it triggers the right item with "ui-menuitem-link ui-corner-all" class.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Dim elements As Object, element As Object
Set elements = objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")

For Each element In elements
    If element.ClassName = "ui-menuitem-link ui-corner-all" Then
        element.Click
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Your code almost did it! Problem is: "ui-menuitem-link ui-corner-all" is the class name, and like I said, I've got 4 other elements with the same class name, so the if becomes true for another element. I'll try to make another if to count the number of attempts until it reaches 5, and that would be the right element.

Answer (score 0):

You can also "cheat" and simulate a mouse click rather than trying to do it through the HTML code. Though, in order to have this solution to work, you should not touch the mouse while the code is running.

How to apply it :

1. Insert these functions declaration on top of your module :

   ```
   Public Declare Function SetCursorPos Lib "user32" (ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long) As Long
   Public Declare Sub mouse_event Lib "user32" (ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dx As Long, ByVal dy As Long, ByVal cButtons As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)
   Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = &H2
   Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = &H4
   Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

   Private Sub LeftClick()
     mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
     Sleep 50
     mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0
   End Sub
   ```
2. Get the pixels position of the button : In order to do this, try different values with the `SetCursor` function until you find the position of your button.
   Remember, the first variable represents the pixel position on the axis X and the second one from axis Y with position 0 being on the top left from your screen
3. To simulate the left click, add this :

   ```
    SetCursor 200 , 400 ' Change those numbers by the one syou have found at step 2
    Call LeftClick
   ```

Comment: This might be useful for some other tasks I have in mind! However, I can't risk messing the entire process if someone touches the mouse by mistake. Thanks anyway!